# Azure Backup Agent Error - Contact Support

Tags: azure, backup

I am looking for any advise out there on a error I am getting with the Azure Backup Agent.

A few weeks ago, my free subscription expired and was automatically disabled. I subsequently contacted support and got the service re-enabled in the Azure portal.

Since this time, I have been getting an error on the Azure Backup Agent every time I open it, stating that 'A Problem has occurred with Azure' and 'please contact Microsoft Support' if the problem persists. The Backup Agent will not let me do anything, it is completely locked out (listing no jobs or other options to be able to click on), however it keeps on running every day and I am unable to stop it.

Upon logging a support request via the Azure portal, I have been informed that I need to purchase a support package to be able to receive any technical support.

I have tried searching the usual forums, and have not been able to find anything in regards to this specific problem.

I am posting here in the hope that someone can advice me on how to resolve the error, or alternately how to get someone from Microsoft to respond to me without it costing me an additional $40 per month.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you try to connect / configure over Powershel? If not, and In the absence of getting Azure support to figure it out, my first thought would be to uninstall it from the VM  and reinstall. If that doesn't work, create another vault to test against,if that does work, unless there is required data in there, delete the faulty vault. and move to the new one. If your problem is that you've got a year's worth of backups in there that you need, you might just have to pay!

Comment: I tried un-installing, and re-installing the agent on the server, and at least now it is responsive in the plugin UI again. 

Now it is listing a tone of failed backup jobs within the UI, however the Azure Management Portal is saying that there are no Jobs recorded, but we are still using 250GB of storage. I think it must still be somehow of out sync.

Note that it is a on-premise physical server and I am using the Azure Backup Agent for Windows Essentuals.

Comment: ps. Thanks for your suggestions Michael.